# Setting String value using loop

Tags: java

Given string is `String s1=new String()`
Using for loop I want to change s1 value as 
if loop run one time then it should be `s1="?"` , 
if loop run two times then it should be `s1="?,?"` ,
if loop run three times then it should be `s1="?,?,?"` and so on.
How it will be possible?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: I cant understood what you are talking about?

Comment: I'm talking about you showing us what you have tried. We don't really give out code on SO.

Comment: Please read the SO FAQ if you don't understand. This is a somewhat bad question as it doesn't obey a lot of SO rules (even though I have already seen worse questions)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try,

```
String s1 = "";
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
     s1+=",?";
}
s1 = s1.replaceFirst(",", "");
System.out.println(s1);
```

*Output*

```
?,?,?
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `StringBuilder`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int n = 10; // Number of iterations
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i != n - 1) { // if it's not the last iteration
            sb.append("?,");
        } else {
            sb.append("?");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

**Output:**

```
?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?
```

**Note:**

If you want it as a `String`, just add at the end:

```
String s1 = sb.toString();
```